How to prevent IAM user to access other user owned AWS dynamo db tables?
I am trying to provide  user "Guest" to full dynamo db access except tables not owned by "Guest". I have created the below policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:ListTables"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:OwnerIAMUser": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::909090912345:user/Guest"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

User "Guest" able to create a new table but can't view the tables. I am not sure what to pass in the Action section for Deny.

Guest is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:ListTables

Thank you.

what is dynamodb:OwnerIAMUser ??

That's incorrect. Let me retest

You really want to be careful granting dynamodb:* permissions -- it means they can use DeleteTable to remove the table!

Take a look at Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon DynamoDB - Service Authorization Reference. It lists all the Conditions that can be specified on each DynamoDB Action. I could not see anything that filters table access by username, however there are capabilities to limit rows by user, see: Using IAM policy conditions for fine-grained access control - Amazon DynamoDB

In the general case, IAM users don't own resources. If you want to implement a solution like that, you might typically consider a tagging approach.
